# Unmodifiable List in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, unmodifiable

I'm trying to set a `List` unmodifiable.

In my code, I have a method which returns a list.

This list shouldn't be modified, but I don't want to catch the exception returned by the unmodifiableList.

```
private List<T> listeReferenceSelectAll = null;
List<T> oListeRet = new ArrayList<T>();
oListeRet = listeReferenceSelectAll;
return new ArrayList<T>(oListeRet);
```

It is an existing code and I have to transform it to return an unmodifiable list, but if an "add" method has been called, no exception has to be caught.

First I have create a class which implements List to override "add" method to log the exception and not to catch it.

But I don't know how to correctly instantiate it...

Comment: Assuming it's not homework, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)

Comment: It's very hard to understand the code snippet you've given as it appears to be partly in a method and partly not. It's also not clear what you mean by "i dont want to catch the exception" - which exception? Do you really mean you want a list which silently *ignores* any attempt to modify it? Ick!

Comment: Use the collections package, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: When you do oListeRet = listeReferenceSelectAll, you lose the reference to the array list you created. I suspect this not what you intend.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand your concern. But he didn't say that he wants to **silently** ignore attempts to modify the list. And I think he made a pretty good point on why exceptions are unacceptable here. In his "10 year old application" there are probably other ways to get developer's attention, like extensive error logs that are read by the maintaining developer every day. Therefore I find his minimally invasive approach to clean up code step by step very legitimate and actually quite smart.

Comment: @LumpN: It still feels wrong to me. If you call `add` and it doesn't fail, but it also doesn't add the item to the list, that sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely must do this, try to follow the contract specified by *java.util.List* in the list you are creating.

Your code would look something like

```
public class UnmodifiableArrayList<E>  extends ArrayList<E> {

    public UnmodifiableArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    public boolean add(int index) {
        return false;//Returning false as the element cannot be added 
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        return false;//Returning false as the element cannot be added 
    }

    public E remove(int index) {
        return null;//Returning null as the element cannot be removed
    }
}
```

Add any more methods you need on the same lines. Just **ensure that all the constructors and methods that might by used to modify in your code are overriden**, so as to ensure the list is unmodifiable.

Using the Collections API is the cleaner and better way to do it, so use this way only if using Collections.UnmodifiableList does not satisfy your need.

And keep in mind this will be a nightmare while debugging so log as much as possible.

Comment: @user2346325 you can't seriously accept this answer when all others list the correct "official" way to do it!

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd - I agree this is a very dirty way of doing it, so i mentioned it the end of the answer again to use Collections API as it is a standard way of doing it, and to use this approach only if there is no other way.

Comment: I know it's not the good way to do it but the application is 10 years old and bad code is everywhere.Collections API can have bad side effects in the application context. I will keep the 2 solutions,test them, and wait till monday for a person who know the application pretty much well than me.

Comment: So you're going to compound the problem by adding more bad code?  And please point out the "bad effects"?  How are those more harmful than adding more bad code?

Comment: "Collections API can have bad side effects in the application context" What on earth do you mean by that?

Comment: At the moment,the application doesnt allow to throw the exception from collection API nor discontinue the process. So I am obliged to find a solution that works without throwing an exception but that just doesnt allow to modify. So what I am looking for is a List which doesnt provide a "set" method.

Comment: By doing this you will introduce hidden bugs in your code anywhere the code is expecting the `add` method to work.  In the original post there was a statement about logging the exception.  If you are planning to migrate the code then logging the exception will help you find the places that need updating.  If you don't plan to log instances where attempts are made to modify the list and later correct those lines of code... then I don't recommend silently ignoring requests to add/remove elements from the list!

Comment: this is not the correct way to do, please consider using Collections.unmodifiableList

Answer (score 74):

You need `java.util.Collections`:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(oListeRet);
```

If you have to write your own, have that class implement the `List` interface and throw exceptions for the methods that modify contents.

Answer (score 23):

[Collections.unmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29)

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. This method allows
>   modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists.
>   Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the specified
>   list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether direct or via
>   its iterator, result in an UnsupportedOperationException. The returned
>   list will be serializable if the specified list is serializable.
>   Similarly, the returned list will implement RandomAccess if the
>   specified list does.

Answer (score 11):

`Java-9` provides a new methods to create [unmodifiable/immutable](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#immutable) `List`:

```
jshell> List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3);
list ==> [1, 2, 3]

jshell> list.add(10);
|  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException thrown: 
|        at ImmutableCollections.uoe (ImmutableCollections.java:70)
|        at ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableList.add (ImmutableCollections.java:76)
|        at (#6:1)
```

[List.of](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) creates an immutable list containing an arbitrary number of elements.

Comment: He clearly said that he doesn't want to throw an exception

Answer (score 8):

Although the accepted answer addresses the request of omitting / swallowing the `UnsupportedOperationException`, there should be an explanation of why it's an undesirable practice.

1) The overall intent to swallow an exception is a contradiction of the "fail-fast" principle. Instead of finding and catching defects early they are just allowed to go "under the carpet" turning into time bombs.

2) Not throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` is a direct violation of `List`'s contract which says:

```
Throws:
    UnsupportedOperationException - if the add method is not supported by this list.
```

So the proper answer to what is written in the question's title: "Unmodifiable List in java" should still be:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(oListeRet);
```

Answer (score 2):

1) These lines make no sense

```
List<T> oListeRet = new ArrayList<T>();
oListeRet = listeReferenceSelectAll;
```

2) Use Collections.unmodifiableList.

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(oListeRet);
```

You dont need to catch exception it may throw, they are all UnsupportedOperationException - RuntimeExceptions

Answer (score -1):

The comments about unmodifiable list are correct. Make a method accessor that calls Collections.unmodifiableList. However, you may want to just use an array like so, and use a list internally.

```
 public MyObject[] getObjects() {
    return (MyObject[]) mList.toArray();
 }
```

Comment: Casting arrays in Java almost never works and also does not solve the problem in the required way.