# How do I make a Map<String, List<String> unmodifiable?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, unmodifiable

The `java.util.Collections` class allows me to make collection instances unmodifiable. The following method

```
protected Map<String, List<String>> getCacheData() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(tableColumnCache);
}
```

returns an umodifiable `Map`, so that an `UnsupportedOperationException` is caused by attempting to alter the map instance.

```
@Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
public void checkGetCacheData_Unmodifiable() {
    Map<String, List<String>> cacheData = cache.getCacheData();
    cacheData.remove("SomeItem");
}
```

Unfortunately all `List<String>` childs aren't unmodifiable. So I want to know whether there is a way to enforce the unmofiable behavior for the child values `List<String>` too?

*Of course, alternatively I can iterate through the maps key value pairs, make the lists unmodifiable and reassemble the map.*

Comment: Use final access modifier

Comment: Use unmodifiable lists as the values in your map http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)

Comment: @Ashokkuttuva that's incorrect, final stops you from creating a new instance of the object, you can still modify the contents of a list if it's made final.

Comment: @Ashokkuttuva  final ---> Assignment.  Not the content.  Prefer to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049697/why-final-instance-class-variable-in-java

Comment: @OP not possible with default one I guess. Write one on your own ,As per your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356232/unmodifiable-list-in-java

Comment: The map has no influence on how the lists deal with their data, so indeed, the only thing you can do is create an unmodifiable map of unmodifiable lists.

Comment: @Tom This would be the alternative approach. But I don't want to explicitely make each `List<String>` child of the `Map` unmodifiable. What I'm searching for is a framework functionality that recursively makes the map and it's child Collections unmodifiable.

Comment: @My-Name-Is It appears that the solution to your question doesn't solve your problem. So your question is probably not accurate. Why is subclassing Map to modify it to return unmodifiable lists not sufficient? Maybe try to rethink your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an ImmutableMap full of ImmutableList instances.  Use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to preserve your sanity.

To start off, create ImmutableList instances that you require:

```
ImmutableList<String> list1 = ImmutableList.of(string1, string2, etc);
ImmutableList<String> list2 = ImmutableList.of(string1, string2, etc);
```

Then create your ImmutableMap:

```
ImmutableMap<String,List<String>> map = ImmutableMap.of("list1", list1, "list2", list2);
```

There are numerous ways to instantiate your immutable lists and maps, including builder patterns.  Check out the JavaDocs for [ImmutableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) and [ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you will need to wrap each List as an unmodifiable `List`. This can be done by using `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(...)`. If you have control over the creation of the `Lists`, then you can (and should) do this immediately after you set your values. If you don't have control over the creation of these collections, then you may want to rethink making it unmodifiable because some other code you are unaware of may be relying on that behavior. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that's not exactly what you need but I recommend to use Guava [immutable list multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html)

Comment: A ListMultiMap is not the same thing as Map<String, List<String>>

Comment: @JasonNichols please give me the reasons why could I use  Map<String, List<String>> instead of ListMultiMap

Comment: An ImmutableListMultiMap is simply an immutable implementation of a MultiMap, which allows multiple keys in a single map, that's not the same as a Map<String, List>.  I'll post some code

Answer (score 0):

Subclass Map to return unmodifiable lists.

Comment: Why do that when you can use ready made ImmutableList and ImmutableMap instances?

Comment: He is creating a map with modifiable lists. When he pulls from the map, he wants to ensure that the lists are unmodifiable. The original lists are modifiable.

Comment: Right, and by using Guava's ImmutableMap and Immutable List the entire  structure is unmodifiable

Comment: I like this solution, since I dont't rely on third party libs. In case that the solution can easily be done with few lines of additional source I prefere this solution. 
`private class CacheMap extends Hashtable<String, List<String>> {
 @Override
 public List<String> get(Object key) {
  List<String> cacheData = super.get(key);
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(cacheData);
 }
}`

Comment: I don't know why he doesn't want to use Guava. Maybe he doesn't want to be dependent on a third party library and all of it's transient dependencies to solve a simple problem he can manage himself. This is the solution he decided to go with. It could also be asked, "Why use Guava when Java provides unmodifiable list in the API?"

Comment: @My-Name-Is: The other methods on the map will still return the original lists, for example `iterator()`, and the `values()` view.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Thanks, you are right. I now updated the implementation to:
`private class ImmutableCacheMap extends Hashtable<String, List<String>> {
 protected ImmutableCacheMap(Map<String, List<String>> mutableCache) {
  Map<String, List<String>> tmp = new Hashtable<String, List<String>>();
  Iterator<String> iter = mutableCache.keySet().iterator();
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
   String key = (String) iter.next();
   List<String> value = mutableCache.get(key);
   tmp.put(key, Collections.unmodifiableList(value));
  }
  super.putAll(Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmp));
 }
}`