# How do I avoid .clone()?

Tags: java, arrays

Consider this class

```
class MyClass {
  private MyData[] data;

  public MyData[] getData() {
    return data == null ? null : (MyData[]) data.clone();
  }
```

This is creating issue

> Security - Method returns internal array
>
> Exposing internal arrays directly allows the user to modify some code
>   that could be critical. It is safer to return a copy of the array.

Considering `clone` is bad and should be avoided, what can I do to make this code better?

Comment: simply copy the array?

Comment: `System.arraycopy` or `Arrays.copyOf` both might do what you want.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? a read only array? otherwise just return data by itself.

Comment: @RalphWiggum that will return a shallow copy. Careful with that.

Comment: That doesn't look like an issue. Not all warnings are issues, they're just telling you that you should understand what you're doing and accept the consequences of what you're doing. But not an issue.

Comment: For anyone interested, [Why people are so afraid of using clone() (on collection and JDk classes)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597965/why-people-are-so-afraid-of-using-clone-on-collection-and-jdk-classes)

Comment: @RichardChambers Wow.. that link is gold actually. Thanks

Comment: see unmodifiable list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356232/unmodifiable-list-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to return a copy of the array would probably be by calling [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-):

```
public MyData[] getData() {
    return data == null ? null : Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
}
```

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ `Arrays#copyOf` uses `System.arraycopy` behind the scenes and this is easier to call/understand.

Answer (score 2):

I too agree that clone is bad but Not on Arrays. Clone performs well on array. Your code is clean .Keep it as it is.

Soon I'll attach the reference for Josh Bloch words on array clone.

[Josh Bloch on Cloning](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

> Doug Lea goes even further. He told me that he doesn't use clone anymore except to copy arrays. **You should use clone to copy arrays, because that's generally the fastest way to do it**. But Doug's types simply don't implement Cloneable anymore. He's given up on it. And I think that's not unreasonable.

If you completely avoid cloning, the next best option is

```
System.arraycopy(array1,0, array2, 0, array1.length);
```

because

`Arrays.copyOf` creates another array object internally and returns it where as System.arraycopy uses the passed array.

Comment: I would wipe any code that uses `.clone` and replace it with proper code.

Comment: @daydreamer In that case  `System.arraycopy` is your friend.