# How to Create Immutable Class with List<String> Element in class

Tags: java, arraylist, immutability, immutable-collections

Immutable Class with List

```
package com.text.immutable;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

// An immutable class Student
public final class Student 
{ 
    final String name; 
    final int regNo; 
    final List<String> courses;  // want to make Immutable 

    public Student(String name, int regNo, List<String> courses) 
    { 
        this.name = name; 
        this.regNo = regNo; 
        this.courses = Collections.unmodifiableList(courses);
    } 
    public String getName() 
    { 
        return name; 
    } 
    public int getRegNo() 
    { 
        return regNo; 
    } 

    public List<String> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }
}
```

Testing Immutable Class to Break Immutability

```
package com.text.immutable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class ImmutablityTest 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        List<String> courses = new ArrayList<String>();
        courses.add("java");
        courses.add("spring");
        courses.add("hibernate");
        courses.add("rest");

        Student s = new Student("ABC", 101, courses); 

        System.out.println("Before Update List");
        System.out.println(s.getName()); 
        System.out.println(s.getRegNo()); 
        System.out.println(s.getCourses());
        courses.add("Hibernate"); // Able to Change which affect final OutCome
        //s.getCourses().add("SpringBoot"); // giving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

        System.out.println("After Update List");
        System.out.println(s.getName()); 
        System.out.println(s.getRegNo()); 
        System.out.println(s.getCourses());

    } 
}
```

Output is

```
Before Update List
ABC
101
[java, spring, hibernate, rest]
After Update List
ABC
101
[java, spring, hibernate, rest, Hibernate]
```

why and how this new Course element added into the List as its from Client Side can be added up any time so how we can fix this issue as this immutable class should not allow to modifying after once created

Comment: Clone the List, when setting it.

Comment: i'm always mixing them up - so your question is very reasonable +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this.courses = Collections.unmodifiableList(courses);

That creates, as the name says, an *unmodifiable* list. But that is just a *view* on the **original** list. Thus changes to that *original* list become visible in your "unmodifiable" view.

When in doubt: clone your list, like:

```
this.courses = new ArrayList<>(courses);
```

And then ensure that your **getter** does:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(courses);
```

Comment: yes - it has to be unmodifiable - not immutable ^_^ +1

Comment: `this.courses = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(courses));` should also be suffice

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat  yours also working but Koziolek also working which one is better and proper solution

Answer (score 2):

Not the best in context of memory, but works:

```java
// An immutable class Student
public final class Student 
{ 
    final String name; 
    final int regNo; 
    final List<String> courses;  // want to make Immutable 

    public Student(String name, int regNo, List<String> courses) 
    { 
        this.name = name; 
        this.regNo = regNo; 
        this.courses = new ArrayList(courses);
    } 
    public String getName() 
    { 
        return name; 
    } 
    public int getRegNo() 
    { 
        return regNo; 
    } 

    public List<String> getCourses() {
        return new ArrayList(courses);
    }
}
```

On input (in constructor) you create copy of list and on output (in getter) you create copy.

Comment: Thanks @Koziolek yours also working but GhostCat also working which one is better and proper solution

Answer (score 1):

read [about immutableLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.htm#JSCOR-GUID-DD066F67-9C9B-444E-A3CB-820503735951) and you'll find that an **Immutable and Unmodifiable Are Not the Same**.

I guess (from your question) you are expecting an **unmodifiable list** which you simply don't create...

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356232/unmodifiable-list-in-java) for a proper solution

Answer (score 0):

With `Collections.unmodifiableList`, it creates a wrapper around the original list and that wrapper object is unmodifiable. The original list can still be updated.

So, in order for the `List<String> courses` list to be immutable, you can use Apache collection common library.

`List<String> immutableList = 
                com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.of("Geeks", "For","Geeks");`

ImmutableList has overridden the List.add method to always throw exception `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

---

Second alternative is to create the list inside the constructor itself.

```
public Student(String name, int regNo,  String... args) 
{ 
    this.name = name; 
    this.regNo = regNo; 
    courses = (List)Arrays.asList(args);

}
```

And call it like this :

```
 Student s = new Student("ABC", 101, "a","a","a","a");
```